# Typedef for STL Vector does not compile in XCode

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, stl

I have some code written in C++ which I would like to use in my iPhone app. I added the source files to the XCode project, but I have problem with some parts of the source code, e.g. I have he following code:

```
#import <vector>
// (...) some other code
typedef std::vector<keypoint> keypointslist;
// (...) rest of the code
```

In the line with the typedef I'm getting:

> Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before ':' token in

Exactly the same code was compiled with gcc on Linux machine, so I wonder why XCode has problem with it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `#include <vector>`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, you told XCode to compile the file as C++ and not as C or Objective-C? Maybe you must use the file extension ".cpp".

Comment: the thing is that it is in the header file, so with the extension .h. In the info page of the file I changed the File type property to "sourcecode.cpp.h", but it hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `#include`, not `#import`:

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: He is using XCode for an iPhone app, which probably means he's using an Objective-C, C++ combination. Is there a reason import would not work here?

Comment: Initially there was include, but I changed it to import in case there vector was included many times. Still, nor include nor import works.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone: Well, he said he's using C++ and his compiler complains about the `:` after `std`. A possible explanation would be that the compiler doesn't know about the namespace `std` and therefore gets confused. If `<vector>` would have been included correctly the compiler would know about namespace `std`. Since the line that should include `<vector>` looks dubious my guess is that the problem lies there. The other possibility is that there is some syntax problem in the "(...) some other code" part that causes this error, but we'd need to see more context for that.

Comment: Basically there are some import statements and definitions of structures, then goes the typedef.  But your point about the problem with <vector> might be valid. In some other source file I'm getting an error in the #import <vector> line - "Vector: No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1):

+1 with Ludger,

youre adding that to an objective c app, you'll need to add a .cp/.mm/.cpp translation unit to the project to get that to compile - right click on project classes select add class make sure you add one from the cpp section.

Answer (score 1):

If you include C++ code in a ".m" file you must rename the extension to ".mm" or ".M". this applies even if you reference a C++ class from an objective C one, the file must be renamed. Sometimes this renaming has a domino effect and so you end up with a lot of ".mm" files in your project.

Comment: +1 - this worked for me. I keep forgetting about this bloody domino effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you included `<vector>` header file before typedef. It looks like the compiler doesn't know `std` namespace.

Comment: Yes, the include/import statement is in the beginning of the file (before the typedef).

Answer (score 0):

You have to rename the ALL files that use the C++ code with .mm extension.

That includes your view controller files that could be importing the C++ class. eg. MyViewController.mm